# How can I retrieve subscriber count from YouTube API without oAuth?

Tags: node.js, youtube

I want to retrieve the sub count of a YouTube channel I do not own.
I want to use that data object to have a bot tweet out the number every hour.
How can I do this without the use of Auth and without using a web browser. This project doesn't use a web browser so I don't want to have to make a html page and have it displayed on a website or something.
I just want to get the object and pass it to my twitter bot who will then have it tweeted.
I'm using JavaScript and node

Comment: Next time you post a question, you should tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube provides an API which can be queried by going to the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={{ID}}&key={{KEY}}
```

Make sure to replace the `{{ID}}` with the ID of the channel you want to query and `{{KEY}}` with your API key. 
Make sure to install the `request` node module. With Node.js installed you can just do `npm install --save-dev request`

```
var request = require('request');

// Replace id and key with the accountId and an API key.
var id = "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw";
var key = "AIzaSyAyWsBUsAChiYPDOptU-NBAh_p7oExR1oc";

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" + id + "&key=" + key;

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}, function (err, response, text) {
    if (err) {

        return;
    }

    var json = JSON.parse(text);

    console.log(json.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
});
```

I've tested the code and it's working fine.

### Issues

The `key` will probably eventually stop working as YouTube won't consider it valid any more, causing the request to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

## Update (don't try this approach):

YouTube seems to rely on JS these days to render the page and `cheerio` will only fetch the static HTML page and parse it. The subscriber account is probably retrieved once the page is rendered and then displayed on the page with JS, which `cheerio` cannot do. Therefore, the following approach does not work on this specific website.

## Original:

Fetch the page with an HTTP request and then parse it with [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). Cheerio works a lot like jQuery if you have experience with that - it just parses the HTML and allows you to use jQuery selectors to get the bit of HTML you want.

I also used [request](https://github.com/request/request) to make the HTTP request for me.

Below is a rough example of what you might need to do.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

// Replace "user_account" with the account name.
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/user_account";

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}, function (err, response, html) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

        return;
    }

    let $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var subscribers = $('#subscriber-count').text();

    // use subscribers...
});
```

### Issues

YouTube could change the page at any time which might cause the code not to work as it requires the page to be setup in a specific way.

Comment: im trying to do exactly like this..sorry in advance im new to backend programming.   https://codepen.io/ch-syr3/pen/LXoRxP?editors=0012  it works on code pen but not in my program. i just want to console log the number of total subscribers. on line 13 says "Create a script element to execute the API URL" can someone explain what this is?

Comment: @user8360723 This is out of the scope of StackOverflow at this point as questions and answers are supposed to be more precise rather than being a general lesson about how to program something. However, I've updated the codepen you provided with some comments about how it works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQXKMz I'll provide a better answer to your question as well.